# property not visible outside of interface on iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a view controller, which creates 2 view controllers inside it.  Inside each of these child controllers I wanted to create a property, which would be public, and accessible from the parent controller.

I am using the following method

```
TableViewController.h

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSInteger projectId;
}

@property NSInteger projectId;
```

---

```
TableViewController.m

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize projectId;

...

@end
```

---

I was then expecting the parent view controller to be able to create the child and access the parentId variable:

```
ParentViewController.h

#import "TableViewController.h"
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController {
    TableViewController* tableViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TableViewController* tableViewController;
```

---

```
ParentViewController.m

@implementation ParentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tableViewController.projectId = 100;
}
```

However, the property `projectId` is not found, and returns the error - Request formember 'projectId'in something not a structure or a union.

If I change the line

```
self.tableViewController.projectId = 100;
```

to

```
[self.tableViewController setProjectId:100];
```

I get the warning - 'TableViewController' may not respond to '-setProjectId'

I am compiling this within XCode 4 preview 2, but also have the same issue within XCode 3.2

I am obviously missing something obvious, but cannot work out what it is.

Why can I not access this property?

Comment: Do you have a nib for it called `TableViewController`?

Comment: Yes I do.  Everything works fine, except that the property is not accessible.  I thought it might of been a bug in the new IDE, but doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had 2 copies of the TableViewController files.  One had all my changes, the other was empty.  I had initially created the file in the wrong directory and when I deleted it I had just removed it from the project.

Once I deleted these bogus files, everything worked fine.

Silly me!

Comment: What an annoyance! I thought Xcode would warn you in situations like that. Hopefully, this will get better in Xcode4

Comment: Yes, annoyingly the file I was editing in XCode 4 was not the one included with the compile.  How odd.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#import` your `.h` files in the corresponding `.m` files?

Comment: Apparently so.  Definitely looks like it to me.  I think I will look at it with fresh eyes in the morning.